# ¿Cómo prevenir la activación automática del CheckBox cuando se carga la página? Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, eventos, listview, checkbox

Mi vista tiene un `ListView` donde cada uno de los elementos que se muestran contienen un `CheckBox`. El problema es que cuando la vista carga, si un elemento `CheckBox` viene con el valor `IsChecked = true` hace que se dispare inmediatamente el evento CheckedChanged

El código que estoy usando es el siguiente:

En mi vista ChecklistView.xaml tengo este `ListView`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Checklist.Items}"
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            SeparatorVisibility="None"
            ItemTapped="listViewItems_ItemTapped"
            x:Name="listViewItems">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <views:ItemView />
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

ItemView es un `ContentView` que tiene el `CheckBox`:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Checklist.Views.Checklist.ItemView">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" x:Name="itemCheck" CheckedChanged="itemCheck_CheckedChanged" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Y el codebehind de ItemView contiene el método que se dispara cuando el `CheckBox` cambia de estado:

```
void itemCheck_CheckedChanged(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Pero esto también se ejecuta cuando se carga la página y
    //el CheckBox tiene el valor del Binding en true
}
```

Lo que espero del `CheckBox` es que active el evento `CheckedChanged` SÓLO cuando el usuario cambie su estado y no que se active cuando se cargue la vista.

Comment: Tu binding IsChecked que valor le manda por defecto?

Comment: Siempre viene un valor ahí, y sólo puede ser true o false porque se enlaza a una propiedad tipo bool.

Comment: Si se que es una bool, pero lo tenes que pueda ser null?

Comment: No, el valor por defecto no puede ser nulo.

Comment: Porque no le haces el cambio con el evento Tapped del listview?

Comment: Porque la funcionalidad pide que el "check" de un elemento se realice cuando se haga clic en el CheckBox, no en toda la celda del item del ListView. Además, el ItemTapped del ListView lo pienso usar para mostrar más detalles del elemento en otra vista.

Comment: Podes hacerle una bandera al evento para que no entre la primera vez cuando carga la pagina, que en realidad me parece que entra cuando le pasa el ItemSource y ahi detecta el cambio.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer por lo que mencionas, es crear una recarga en el OnAppearing() siempre en el code behind.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        itemCheck.IsChecked = false;

    }

     void itemCheck_CheckedChanged(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

El usuario siempre tendría el acceso a marcarlo y cambiar su estado.